# Eclipse JPA Tools: Connect with service name instead of SID

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

I am trying to generate entities from the database tables using JPA Tools features in eclipse.

I am aware that we can use service name and connect using

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.hostserver.mydomain.ca:1234/ABCD
```

The problem is that we don't have SID due to some constraints and JPA Tools doesn't allow me to edit the connection URL. Connection URL is a non-editable field in the "New Connection" screen. URL is formed based on the inputs the user enters. I have referred to multiple SO questions but it didn't help. Any pointers are appreciated.

JPA Tools screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the fix.

- In the dropdown for 'Drivers', select 'Other Oracle Driver'
- Mention the full connection URL
- Test connection

That's it!